# Update sql com 2 condições

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Tenho uma tabela com a coluna **STATUZ**
Essa coluna é composta por 3 possíveis valores: NOVO, VISUALIZADO, DESCARTADO

Eu tenho uma função onde preciso implementar uma linha SQL que faça um update em minha tabela e altere todos os valores da coluna **STATUZ** para: DESCARTADO

A lógica é:

Atualizar em: ***minhatabela***, a coluna: statuz - onde tiver o valor NOVO para DESCARTADO, e onde tiver o valor VISUALIZADO para DESCARTADO. (de uma vez)

o comando que estou usando, mas não surte efeito é:

```
 UPDATE toyota_base SET statuz = 'DESCARTADO' WHERE statuz = 'NOVO' and statuz = 'VISUALIZADO';
```

Toda ajuda é bem vinda. Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`statuz` tem apenas um valor só, então ele **não** pode ser ao mesmo tempo `NOVO` **e** `VISUALIZADO` por isso o update não altera nenhum registro.

Troque o `AND` (conjunção) por `OR` (disjunção)

```
UPDATE toyota_base SET
   statuz = 'DESCARTADO'
WHERE statuz = 'NOVO' or statuz = 'VISUALIZADO';
```

Ou utilize a clásula IN() que terá o mesmo efeito.

```
UPDATE toyota_base SET
   statuz = 'DESCARTADO'
WHERE statuz IN('NOVO','VISUALIZADO');
```

Comment: Opa, Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo...